# Changing value of a behaviour subject in Angular

Tags: angular

So I have a service which holds the value of a Behavior Subject like this

```
incidentReportFilter = new BehaviorSubject<ReportPayload>({
    filter: DefaultFilter.getDefaultObject(),
    activityLogFilter: ActivityLogManagerDefaultFilter.getDefaultObject(),
    hrFilter: HrFormDefaultFilter.getDefaultObject(),
    pageNumber: 1,
    pageSize: 2,
    sortBy: "date",
    sortOrder: 1,
});
```

So I subscribing to this subject in one of my components. The thing is that if something changes like a single value from this object I need to call something but by just the latest value and keeping the values of all others keys.

So I am doing something like this, a redux approach I think.

```
this.reportsFilterService.incidentReportFilter.next({
  ...this.reportsFilterService.incidentReportFilter.value,
  filter: filter
});
```

Is this correct approach? It is working but is it a good approach is what I am concerned it.

Comment: I would say that yes, it's a good approach. One small note: when overwriting the filter, you can remove the `: filter` part and just keep the `filter` since the key and the value have the same name

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your use case. General approaches are:

- Emit the whole object (as you have done).
- Have a `incidentReportFilterChange` subject with the type `Partial<ReportPayload>` and emit only changed property.
- Have multiple subjects for each or a group of dynamic properties and consume them with a `combineLatest` (or a similar operator based on the requirements).